# MLA parenthetical citation of a character in a novel

Tags: novel, characters, mla, citations

If I am writing my essay on only one novel, and I have made it clear in the previous sentence that the quote is from a character in said novel, do I still have to include the authors name in the parenthesis, or just the page number?

Answer (score 1):

When a subsequent quotation is from the same work as the previous one, a page number is enough:

> In Bob Foo's novel *Living the Internet Life*, the protagonist is posting comments on websites. His first comment is met with enthusiastic upvoting (34). The protagonist is happy and decides to post more comments (38).